# Differnet orientations for various view controllers?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation, orientation, landscape-portrait

All the application should be displayed in portrait orientation. But some view controllers should be in landscape mode - I want to allow user to display graphs in "fullscreen mode".

How to implement this? The additional difficulty is I need to set the orientation in both cases when I push view controller and pop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the navigation controller than you need to `affine transform` the viewController if your app is in portait mode.For full screen and rotation you can use

```
-(void)setRotationInLandscapeMode:(BOOL)status
{
    if(status)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:status];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectOffset(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame, 0.0, -20.0);
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI * (90) / 180.0));
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 320,568 );
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:status];
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((0));
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 320,568 );
    }
}
```

and change the orientation in `viewWillAppear`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self setRotationInLandscapeMode:YES];
}
```

again change to portrait `viewWillDisappear`

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewWillDisappear:YES];
}
```

You can also consider `supportedInterfaceOrientations` if your viewController is not in navigationController stack

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Comment: `supportedInterfaceOrientations` works for me but it setups the orientations once only (it doesn't work when I push a view controller with another orientation). Your solution `setRotationInLandscapeMode:` could work but it seems you have a mistake with calculations: each time I perform this code my views slightly move up.

Comment: As removing status bar is needed so i have removed and make sure your view is connected with top layout guide in AutoLayout

Comment: you can try without removing `status bar`

Comment: I got another problem: I set a background color of a view inside the view controller. I see that it has a white stripe below the view (empty place) and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: as status bar is hidden view may go up by 20 px.I need to look code for that

Comment: I have found a problem. `CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 568);` should be changed to `CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);`. I can't remove the status bar (or rotate it) using your example but it is enough for me. So fix the rect value please and I will approve your answer.

Comment: oops.. its typo @Gargo thanks for pointing that i have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

This key can be configured in XCode under Target>YourTarget>General>Deployment Info>Device Orientation.
[image]

must be select the **Landscape left** and **Landscape right**.

there is a code in our AppDelegate and called for every view controller that occurs on screen.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{

}
```

write this code in viewcontorllers  which you need only PORTRAIT mode

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
     return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
```

write this method in viewcontorllers  which you need only Landscape mode

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
     return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown);
    //OR return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
```

Comment: Nice but doesn't work at all. I have the same incorrect result I have already got: if I add portrait and landscape orientations in app settings then the app thinks that all these orientations are supported by all the view controllers. Or is a bug of a simulator?